# Using Application ID to automate Seamless SSO kerberos decryption key rollover

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, kerberos

I would like to automate the rollover of kerberos description keys used for seamless SSO. In doing this, I cannot use global administrator USER accounts, as they may receive spray attacks (I cannot use domain IDs as there are so many domains, and thus I will have to make so many Global Admins). I am thinking that by using application ID and certificates, I can securely automate this job.

The problem is, every sample code I could find has uses the "AuthenticationContext". Something like this:

```
New-AzureADSSOAuthenticationContext -CloudCredentials $CloudCredentials
Update-AzureADSSOForest -OnPremCredentials $OnpremCredentials
```

Is it possible to use application IDs to automate this process? And if it is, how do i code it?

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you could not use the service principal(i.e. the application ID) to do that.

Currently, we could just use domain admin and tenant global admin credentials in a scheduled task.

You could refer to this [sample](https://www.joachimloe.com/2018/02/23/automatically-roll-over-the-kerberos-decryption-key-azure-ad-connect-sso/):

```
# Requirements:
# Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant.
# 64-bit Azure Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell.

$CloudUser = 'service_account@domain.com'
$CloudEncrypted = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\Cloud_Encrypted_Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$CloudCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($CloudUser,$CloudEncrypted)
$OnpremUser = 'DOMAIN\service_account'
$OnpremEncrypted = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\Onprem_Encrypted_Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$OnpremCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($OnpremUser,$OnpremEncrypted)

Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\AzureADSSO.psd1'
New-AzureADSSOAuthenticationContext -CloudCredentials $CloudCred
Update-AzureADSSOForest -OnPremCredentials $OnpremCred
```

---

**Besides**, Azure Team is also working on getting this automated, see the feedback:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33773926-automate-seamless-sso-kerberos-decryption-key-roll

Comment: So in our case, we have to create a service ID with global admin role, which could recive spray attacks…This is far from ideal. Thankyou for your answer.

Comment: @beadaman Yes, but it is the only option currently, azure team is working on getting this automated.